# Dynamically change dimensions when opening SWF files with Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, size, fancybox

I have an ul with links to images and swf-files (banners). Upon clicking the links, Fancybox opens its overlay and shows the image / swf-file.

The problem is that whatever the dimensions of the swf-file are, Fancybox always shows an overlay of about 580 * 390. This of course gives a distorted view of the swf files.

I've been tinkering with autoScale and such, with no result... :-(

This is my code:

```
$("a.fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
    'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
        return '<span id="fancybox-title-inside">' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
    }   
});
```

Is there any way that Fancybox can detect the dimensions of the swf-files and determine the dimensions of the overlay as a result?

Please note that I do not have the dimensions of the swf file in a database or something.
Also please note that images and swf's are always mixed at random.

Anxiously awaiting your responses!

Regards,

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, as commented before, to display the SWF files in a separate PHP page, in which you set the the height & width of the SWF via SWFObject, and then using the iframe source setting of fancybox. On the back-end you pass the SWF to this file and that's that!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use FancyBox's autoscale or autodimension options. As described in the [API page](http://fancybox.net/api):

```
autoScale   true    If true, FancyBox is scaled to fit in viewport
autoDimensions  true    For inline and ajax views, resizes the view to the element recieves. Make sure it has dimensions otherwise this will give unexpected results
```

Comment: Thanks, but these settings do not work. My overlay keeps the same dimensions described above.

Answer (score 0):

can you not get the dimensions of the swf using jquery and pass them into the fancybox code using the width and height options as specified in the fancybox documentation.
http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: This sounds like a good solutions. How would one go about determining the dimensions through jquery?

Comment: You'll need to do something along the lines of:

var mySwfWidth = $('#idOfSwf').width();
var mySwfHeight = $('#idOfSwf').height();

then in your properties of the fancybox you would have:

width: mySwfWidth,
height: mySwfHeight

Comment: Problem is that the SWF is loaded externally, not inline. I've seen that you can find the dimensions with php (getimagesize($path_or_url);), but the whole process seems to damn complex...

Comment: Do you have a lnk to the page?

Comment: I've managed to solve it myself, I think. I'm now wrapping the swf files in a PHP document, in which I set the height & width with SFWObject. Thus, I'm using the iframe setting in Fancybox. In my backend, I just check if its a swf file, then I pass this to display-flash.php and voila. Seems like a good solution imho. What do you think?

Comment: If it is working consistently for the different types of media then go for it. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it does work consistently. I check the file extentions beforehand.